# CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction in magento2

Tags: magento2

> [2019-01-30 11:52:41] main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[40001]:  Serialization
>   failure:  1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting
>   transaction,  query was: INSERT INTO `sales_order_grid` (`entity_id`,
>   `status`, `store_id`, `store_name`, `customer_id`, `base_grand_total`,
>   `base_total_paid`, `grand_total`, `total_paid`, `increment_id`,
>   `base_currency_code`, `order_currency_code`, `shipping_name`,
>   `billing_name`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `billing_address`,
>   `shipping_address`, `shipping_information`, `customer_email`,
>   `customer_group`, `subtotal`, `shipping_and_handling`,
>   `customer_name`, `payment_method`, `total_refunded`,
>   `signifyd_guarantee_status`) SELECT sales_order.entity_id AS
>   `entity_id`, sales_order.status AS `status`, sales_order.store_id AS
>   `store_id`, sales_order.store_name AS `store_name`,
>   sales_order.customer_id AS `customer_id`, sales_order.base_grand_total
>   AS `base_grand_total`, sales_order.base_total_paid AS
>   `base_total_paid`, sales_order.grand_total AS `grand_total`,
>   sales_order.total_paid AS `total_paid`, sales_order.increment_id AS
>   `increment_id`, sales_order.base_currency_code AS
>   `base_currency_code`, sales_order.order_currency_code AS
>   `order_currency_code`, TRIM(CONCAT_WS(' ',
>   IF(`sales_shipping_address`.`firstname` <> '',
>   `sales_shipping_address`.`firstname`, NULL),
>   IF(`sales_shipping_address`.`lastname` <> '',
>   `sales_shipping_address`.`lastname`, NULL))) AS `shipping_name`,
>   TRIM(CONCAT_WS(' ', IF(`sales_billing_address`.`firstname` <> '',
>   `sales_billing_address`.`firstname`, NULL),
>   IF(`sales_billing_address`.`lastname` <> '',
>   `sales_billing_address`.`lastname`, NULL))) AS `billing_name`,
>   sales_order.created_at AS `created_at`, sales_order.updated_at AS
>   `updated_at`, TRIM(CONCAT_WS(' ', IF(`sales_billing_address`.`street`
>   <> '', `sales_billing_address`.`street`, NULL),
>   IF(`sales_billing_address`.`city` <> '',
>   `sales_billing_address`.`city`, NULL),
>   IF(`sales_billing_address`.`region` <> '',
>   `sales_billing_address`.`region`, NULL),
>   IF(`sales_billing_address`.`postcode` <> '',
>   `sales_billing_address`.`postcode`, NULL))) AS `billing_address`,
>   TRIM(CONCAT_WS(' ', IF(`sales_shipping_address`.`street` <> '',
>   `sales_shipping_address`.`street`, NULL),
>   IF(`sales_shipping_address`.`city` <> '',
>   `sales_shipping_address`.`city`, NULL),
>   IF(`sales_shipping_address`.`region` <> '',
>   `sales_shipping_address`.`region`, NULL),
>   IF(`sales_shipping_address`.`postcode` <> '',
>   `sales_shipping_address`.`postcode`, NULL))) AS `shipping_address`,
>   sales_order.shipping_description AS `shipping_information`,
>   sales_order.customer_email AS `customer_email`,
>   sales_order.customer_group_id AS `customer_group`,
>   sales_order.base_subtotal AS `subtotal`,
>   sales_order.base_shipping_amount AS `shipping_and_handling`,
>   TRIM(CONCAT_WS(' ', IF(`sales_order`.`customer_firstname` <> '',
>   `sales_order`.`customer_firstname`, NULL),
>   IF(`sales_order`.`customer_lastname` <> '',
>   `sales_order`.`customer_lastname`, NULL))) AS `customer_name`,
>   sales_order_payment.method AS `payment_method`,
>   sales_order.total_refunded AS `total_refunded`,
>   signifyd_case.guarantee_disposition AS `signifyd_guarantee_status`
>   FROM `sales_order`  LEFT JOIN `sales_order_address` AS
>   `sales_shipping_address` ON sales_order.shipping_address_id =
>   sales_shipping_address.entity_id  LEFT JOIN `sales_order_address` AS
>   `sales_billing_address` ON sales_order.billing_address_id =
>   sales_billing_address.entity_id  LEFT JOIN `sales_order_payment` ON
>   sales_order.entity_id = sales_order_payment.parent_id

Comment: And... the question is?

Comment: @RaulSanchez did you find the fix for this? I'm facing a similar issue.

Comment: You'd read the posted answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I cannot comment..

It seems like you were running two processes that have attempted to lock the same database table? Perhaps you were re-indexing and trying to run an import simultaneously?

We will need more details to help.